# How do I beat the Jack in the Box?

Tags: castle-of-illusion

I am trying to beat the Jack in the Box, but every time he has his punching bag out (where he tries to hit me and then hits himself and stuns himself), I take damage.

How do I beat this boss?

Comment: is this question about the [1990 original](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castle_of_Illusion_Starring_Mickey_Mouse) or the [2013 remake](http://store.steampowered.com/app/227600/Castle_of_Illusion/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid getting hit by simply bending over. Afterwards just use the spring he drops to jump on his head. Since this is only the first phase of the boss fight you may also take a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mTfdsobmshw) which shows the complete fight.

Comment: How do I bend over?

Comment: You just have to press "down" on the d-pad.